# How to prevent automatic bookmarks in Nautilus from being created on (bind) mounts?

Tags: nautilus, files, 17.10, fstab, bookmarks

I want to bind my Documents/Music/Pictures folders to a subfolder of a mounted share, but when I add binds in fstab, I keep on getting automatic bookmarks like so:

[image]

As you can see, all 'binded' folders show up twice in the Nautilus shortcut pane.

This 'automatic bookmarking' only happens in the /media and /home/ folders - but is there any way to prevent it from happening  in the /home/ folder, or perhaps with an option/flag in the fstab line? I tried adding `comment=x-gvfs-hide` as suggested in <[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193524/how-to-hide-bind-mounts-in-nautilus)>, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I tried it out as an alternative to symbolic links. It works on Manjaro 20.0.3 Gnome.

From my fstab:

```
# My Storage:
# <file system>               <mount point>         <type> <options>                  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=LONG-NUMBER              /mnt/mydrive          ext4   defaults                   0       0

# My Folders:
# <file system>               <mount point>         <type> <options>                  <dump>  <pass>
/mnt/mydrive/esteban/Bilder   /home/esteban/Bilder  none   defaults,bind,x-gvfs-hide  0       0
```