# x-gvfs-hide in fstab, to hide a folder in file system

Tags: filesystem, fstab, bind

I have placed some large folders on a separate disk, in a single partition, but I want them to show up in my file system as if they were in my root partition. In fstab I mount the separate disk on /extern. The large folders are then in the file system as /extern/videos, /extern/music, but I would rather see just /videos, /music. I've read that, once upon a time, this was possible by mounting /extern with a line in fstab like

UUID=bb906568-0651-4eca-a111-dcab4d1a0bf1   /extern  ext4    defaults,x-gvfs-hide 0 2

I then used "bind" to mount /videos and /music as aliases to /extern/videos and /extern/music. This works, but /extern still also shows up in the file system with its nested folders (/extern/videos and /extern/music), so that /videos and /music show up twice in the file system.

I tried comment=x-gvfs-hide, and I tried putting both variants in the bind column as well. No success.

Anyone know how I can hide the /extern folder?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are expecting to happen. I have a very similar setup, except my external folders come from a ntfs partition instead of a separate disk. I got the effect which i wanted by adding `x-gvfs-hide` to the relevant entries in my /etc/fstab file:

```
UUID=3081902B5B3B414B /media/lukas/data ntfs-3g defaults,auto,user,x-gvfs-hide 0 0
/media/lukas/data/Music /home/lukas/Music none bind,x-gvfs-hide 0 0
/media/lukas/data/Videos /home/lukas/Videos none bind,x-gvfs-hide 0 0
```

Following this, all three of the annoying side bar entries (similar as seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/999284/1082671)) were hidden from my graphical file manager (thunar v4.16.8 in a Xubuntu 21.10). This is what `x-gvfs-hide` does. However it does NOT magically remove the first mount while still keeping the other two. This means when i type `ls /media/lukas/data`, the whole partition - with Music/ and Videos/ subdirectories - will still be visible at this point as well, next to being seamlessly accessible as ~/Music and ~/Videos from both command line and thunar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may have not understood what x-gvfs-hide is supposed to do. In the meantime I have given the partition a dotted name, so that it only shows up when I want to see hidden files + folders.